# Wordpress Query Vars: Filter with value or if key doesn't exists

Tags: wordpress

Im using Wordpress and I added a custom meta_key to a custom post type. Then I added that meta_key as a column in the post's dashboard.

Values for that meta_key are 'yes' and 'no'. But as the meta key isn't added when the post is created, if I found no value, I show 'no' in the column.

Up to there, everything's ok. But when I try to filter, I can get posts with 'yes' meta_key doing this:

```
                $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key' => 'my_custom_key',
                    'value' => 'yes',
                );
```

If I do the same for 'no' I can get all posts with the meta_key set to 'no' BUT NOT the posts where the meta_key isn't set. So for that case I do:

```
                $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key' => 'my_custom_key',
                    'value' => 'no',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                );
```

However I can't get at the same time the posts with meta_key 'no' and the ones without that meta_key, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution... as the main RELATION is AND, I have to create a new tree of relationship like this:

```
                $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'my_custom_key',
                        'value' => 'no',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'my_custom_key',
                        'value' => 'no',
                    )
                );
```